# Button and edittext does not appear

Tags: android

I am doing some sort of chat in my android project. In my layout, all seems working good, but the button and edittext at the bottom of my screen do not appear or show up. How to make it visible.This is my layout.xml:

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_send_message"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editMessage"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="5"
                android:gravity="top|left"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
                android:maxLines="5"
                android:minLines="3"
                android:scrollHorizontally="false" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonSend"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="send"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you set `android:layout_height="fill_parent"` on the `ScrollView`, causing it to take up all of the available space. Set it to `0dp` and add `android:layout_weight="1"` to make room for the lower `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

The ScrollView is getting all the height.
Try:

```
<ScrollView
android:id="@+id/scroll"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:orientation="vertical" >
```